Merge zip file of code in the latest working branch
I have zip file got from another developer, now I want to merge that zip file with my latest codebase.
I sent zip files for changes a month ago, after sending, I made some changes to my dev branch and now got codebase in the zip file after another developer made changes.
When I try to extract zip and copy contents of zip in my working branch that is dev, it removes and overwrites my changes.
What I want is, it should merge the codebase in zip file with my latest codebase without removing my files, I sent the zip without .git folder.
I tried creating another branch, pushing code of zip file in another branch and then merging with my branch but still it overwrites :(
Is it possible to achieve this?

Please don't talk about what you did, as your words can be interpreted in different ways. Show us what you did. Copy and paste right out the terminal so we see what you said to Git and what Git said to you.

How is Git supposed to do a auto-merge of arbitrary code into your code? Merging requires a coherent topology with an appropriate merge base. It doesn't seem like you're understanding that, so you are "surprised" when the contribution on your side of the merge is zero. And what kind of collaboration is a zip file supposed to represent? This sounds like a complete misunderstanding or misuse of Git.

A solution is to create a branch (at the good place, but you have to decide where. At least before your 1st commit introducing your changes) and commit in the branch the files of the zip. Then merge this branch in your's.

The only way to solve this is to create a branch from the time when you created the zip file.
Then the new branch will have all the changes from the zip file without your changes that happened in the meantime and the main branch will have all of your changes.
Then you can merge and resolve conflicts normally without overwriting.
You can create the branch like this
git branch branch_name <commit-hash>

Then checkout the branch
git checkout branch_name

Extract your zip file, and commit the changes
git add .
git commit -m"Developer Changes"

Switch back to you main branch
git checkout main

And then merge
git merge branch_name

